# Import functions to class from a different file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently I have some struggle to get this working. I want to split my class functions into multiple files. I have tried to require them in the main class to merge them, but you know...

```
//server.js
module.exports.server = () => {
  console.log('it works')
}


//handle.js
const server = require('./server')

class handle extends server{
//...
}
module.exports = new handle()

//test.js
const handle = require('./handle')
handle.server() //error
```

Best greetings,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, Arrow functions are not synonymous with normal functions.

You're getting the error because server is `()=>{}`. For a `class` to `extend`,

> The .prototype of the extension must be an Object or null.

**MDN web docs** : [extends keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends)

```
'use strict';

var serverAsArrowFunction = () => {
};

var serverAsNormalFunction = function () {
};

var o = { //this is what happens
  server: () => {
    console.log('it works');
  }
};

console.log('NormalFunction', serverAsNormalFunction.prototype); //{}
console.log('Arrow function', serverAsArrowFunction.prototype); // undefined
console.log('Object', o.prototype); //undefined
```

Next, You're exporting as `Object`. Replacing the arrow function with normal function.

**server.js**

```
module.exports.server = function () {
  console.log('it works -- from server.js');
};
```

**handle.js**

```
const { server } = require('./server');

class handle extends server {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('constructor -- from handle.js');
    }
}
module.exports = new handle();
```

**test.js**

```
const handle = require('./handle');
console.log(handle);
console.log('-- from test.js');
```

Running the code,

```
node test.js
```

Logs

> it works -- from server.js
>   constructor -- from handle.js
>   handle {}
>   -- from test.js

Comment: Well this is working and I appreciate your help! One more question. ist it possible to make this function public instead of private? I would like to use them like **handle.server()**

Comment: I think for you to use to `handle.server()`, you need to have a function within `class handler`.

Comment: I have got it. I have changed all my function to snychrounous and then I was able to declare it inside of the constructor. After this I had the ability to call them in the test.js

Comment: Cool. If you this answer helped you, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

To use functions from another file, you have to export it via JSON. For example:

```
//poker.js
function shuffle(deck){
  //shuffle
}
function dealCards(deck){
  shuffle(deck);
  //deal
}
function createDeck(){
  //creates Deck
}
```

If you only want createDeck and dealCards functions to be used, you export it like so:

```
module.exports={
  deal:dealCards,
  createDeck: createDeck
}
```

And you use it like so:

```
//test.js
var poker=require('./poker.js');
var deck= poker.createDeck();
poker.deal(deck);
```

Comment: You missunterstood me. I want to use a function of a class in test.js that has been declared in server.js although the class has been declared in handle.js. But it is nice to know that I can rename the function while exporting